# Jquery name selector with array

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to get the values of 2 inputs with jQuery but the array selector that we use for checkboxes doesn't work. How can I get the values for the sample code below.

```
<input name="person[name]">
<input name="person[age]">

<script>
    $("input[name='person[]']").val();
</script>
```

Comment: well, for starters the value of the `[name]` attributes is not `person[]` for either of the elements you've shown as an example. Did you try anything else or read the jQuery API?

Comment: I searched it over internet and couldn't find the solution. That's why I am asking here. Regarding the API didn't read it from start to end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `*=` for contain. Or `^=` for begin by.

**Example**

```js
$("input[name*='person['").each(function(){
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="person[name]" value="test">
<input name="person[age]" value="ok">
```

Answer (score 3):

Use combined [attribute starts with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and [attribute ends with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)  selectors. And finally use [`map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map) method to iterate over elements and generate  an array of values. If you just want to iterate over them then [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each) method is enough where `this` can be used to refer the dom object of the element inside the callback.

```
$("input[name^='person['][name$=']']")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="person[name]">
<input name="person[age]">

<script>
  console.log(
    $("input[name^='person['][name$=']']").map(function() {
      return this.value
    }).get()
  )
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="person[name]">
<input name="person[age]">

<script>
  $("input[name^='person['][name$=']']").each(function() {
    console.log(this.value);
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type='checkbox'][name='ProductCode']").each(function(){ ...
```

Comment: Please explain your answer